# C#, handle with Korean string

Tags: c#, encoding

I have application that read json of places in facebook API
I've try to read location in Korea
the string in the json is:

> "name": "\uc9c0\uc9c0\ud5a5",

the result that I have:

> Item["name"].ToString() = [][][][]

how can I encode it right?

I've tried:

```
 Encoding korenEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(50225);
byte[] convertedToUtf8 = Encoding.Convert(korenEncoding,Encoding.UTF8,korenEncoding.GetBytes(Item["name"].ToString()));
string name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(convertedToUtf8);
```

And it didn't work,
Thanks

Comment: You might want to boost up your acceptance numbers...

Comment: If i had an answers to confirm...

Comment: I had also somethink to do with Korean and it turned out, that the problem is not in encoding, but most of standard fonts does not support Korean chars, therefore you see small squares

Comment: so, I need to install font? how can I handle it?

Comment: I figure that if I copy the squares and paste it on browser, I do see korean chars, but if I try to save it to the database it still save in squares. anyone?

Comment: No, whatever program you use to look at the dbase data has the same problem as your debugger.  This is a rare problem to have these days, high time that you retire that ancient version of XP perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what are you using to deserialize the json? I tried with `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` and it decodes it correctly. Also make sure your database columns supports unicode data

```
[DataContract]
class thinger
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name;
}

string snip = @"{""name"": ""\uc9c0\uc9c0\ud5a5""}";
Byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(snip);
MemoryStream jsonstream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
jsonstream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
jsonstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(thinger));
thinger output = (thinger)ser.ReadObject(jsonstream);

//output.name = 지지향
```